# What are the possible ways to deploy a SQL 2016 database to Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have an Azure SQL managed instance ready with me. What all things do I need to configure to deploy a SSMS 2016 database to the managed instance. Can i have a step by step process to perform the deployment? Is there any tool available which can automate this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL provided the tutorial to help you deploy the SSMS 2016 database to Azure SQL managed instance.

Please reference: [SQL Server instance migration to Azure SQL Database managed instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-migrate).

In this article, you learn about the methods for migrating a SQL Server 2005 or later version instance to Azure SQL Database managed instance.

You also can use the [Azure Database Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/dms-overview).

Reference tutorial:

1. [Tutorial: Migrate SQL Server to an Azure SQL Database managed
   instance offline using DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-managed-instance)
2. [Tutorial: Migrate SQL Server to an Azure SQL Database managed
   instance online using DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-managed-instance-online)

They all support SSMS 2016 database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What all settings do I need to configure in azure portal before moving my database to Azure SQL managed instance? Do I need a virtual network to connect my public IP and a route table?

Comment: Yes, you need. Please read the documents carefully , they all have the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-managed-instance#prerequisites) before you migrate the database..